# linux create symlinks based on most recently modified files

Tags: linux, command-line, symlink

I want to recursively search a directory tree and get the 10 most recently modified files.
For each one of these files, i want to create a symlink in my `/home/mostrecent/` directory.

I know i could solve this with a scripting language, but I'm a bit miffed that I can't do it with a linux command!

So far i have this:

```
find /home/myfiles -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort | tail -n 10 | cut -c 32-
```

How do i create a symlink in `/home/mostrecent` for each one of these files, without using a scripting language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `bash` *is* a scripting language, more than capable of doing that sort of stuff even from the command line :-)

Assuming that the command you posted works (and it seems to, based on my cursory testing), you can just do:

```
i=0
for f in $(CMD) ; do
    ln -s $f $HOME/recent$i
    ((i++))
done
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
i=0;for f in $(CMD);do ln -s $f $HOME/recent$i;((i++));done
```

This will create the files `recent0` through `recent9` in your home directory, which are symlinks to the most recent files.

Obviously, you should put your *actual* command where I've put the marker text `CMD` above. I've used the marker just so it formats nicely here on SO.

---

As Jan Hudec points out in a comment, that will only work for files without spaces, evil things in my opinion :-)

But, since people seem to use them, you can use the safer:

```
i=0
CMD | while read f; do
    ln -s $f $HOME/recent$i
    ((i++))
done
```

And, again, the one-liner version:

```
i=0;CMD|while read f;do ln -s $f $HOME/recent$i;((i++));done
```

Comment: I would suggest `put-that-command-here | while read f; do ... done` instead. It has the advantage of properly handling files with spaces (it still won't handle files with newlines, but those are not common; spaces are) and will work even for huge lists that the shell won't like to load in memory all at once.

Comment: That is a very good point, @Jan, I've adjusted the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with sed.

All hail sed!

```
find /home/myfiles/ -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort | tail -n 10 | cut -c 21- | sed -e "s/^/ln -s \"/" -e "s/$/\"/" -e "s/$/ \"\/home\recent\/\"/" | sh
```

If i pipe `sed` to `cat` instead of `sh`, this is the output:

```
ln -s "/home/myfiles/1.simplest" "/home/recent/"
ln -s "/home/myfiles/2.with space" "/home/recent/"
ln -s "/home/myfiles/3.with'apostraphe" "/home/recent/"
ln -s "/home/myfiles/4.with'apostrophe space" "/home/recent/"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create symlinks to several file types modified in the last 24 hrs, with the same filenames (but a different path of course)

Thanks to Pax, Jan and Jon, with a little modification...

Make a 'recent' directory

```
mkdir ~/recent
```

Create 'getrecentfiles.sh' and add...

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
find $HOME -mtime 0 -name \*.txt -print -o \
           -mtime 0 -name \*.pdf -print -o \
           -mtime 0 -name \*.extensionname -print -o | while read f; do
        ln -s $f $HOME/recent/
done
```

filters:

-mtime (n*24hrs) is time since last modified (n=1 shows only files modified bw 24-48hrs ago)

-o is the OR operator for multiple files (default is AND)

Change it to executable, add it to your startup scripts and make a shortcut to ~/recent on your desktop, to have the latest files you want on hand!